# How to enable https protocol in a normal website?

Tags: html, http, ssl, https, dtls

Kindly let me know the number of methods to proceed with this query. It will be really so nice of you for answering my question.

Answer (score 4):

If you want https you need to buy a certifiate.
Here's a useful link: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6073543?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

1. Host the website with a dedicated IP address
2. Buy a SSL certificate from "Certificate Authorities” (CA’s)
3. Activate the certificate
4. Install the certificate
5. Update your site to use HTTPS

Source http://www.howto-expert.com/how-to-get-https-setting-up-ssl-on-your-website/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your question is, but from what I understand here is my input. Please explain your question a little more.
You can try web.config -- it will force HTTPS for ALL resources like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: * Buy a SSL Cerificate
* Install the Certificate or else provide the certificate to your hosting provider.
* Simply copy paste the above code in your .htaccess file

Comment: Please describe, what was the problem and how will this code solve it, to help others understand this answer